# Is possible to order Zabbix items by latest value?

Tags: networking, zabbix, network-monitoring

I have a Zabbix server monitoring more than 600 servers.

I need to create some dashboard or screen that I can see which are the top 10 servers that are consuming more CPU, memory, bandwidth, ...

It's like to get latest data from all servers and order by value desc limiting to 10 rows: `SELECT hostname FROM hosts ORDER BY cpu_usage DESC LIMIT 10`

I'm not sure that is possible to do it using Zabbix. If it's not possible, what do you suggest to use, Grafana is a good option?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad, I'll try to give some advices (most of them are not programming related, so no 100% suitable for SO...).

First of all, you can group host items only if they are homogeneous: you can't mix up a windows CPU usage with a Unix load average, while you can mix up bandwidth usage across different OSes (of course do check for Mbps and MBps unit).

Grafana is great, I use it for a lot of dashboarding but the templating mechanism depends on hosts, groups, application and item names, not on the item values.

You need a specific dashboard, the best course of action is to write your own tool but please *never* select directly from the database. You should use the [API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api)s, specifically `item.get`, `history.get` and `trend.get`.

The difference from history and trend is crucial, you can read it [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/history_and_trends).

You can find [libraries](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/api/libraries) for most modern languages, I'm familiar with python but of course you can use JS, Ruby, PHP etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I'm not sending direct queries to SQL, it was only an example. All the servers are running Linux. I didn't find any method to, for example, fetch the 10 servers with higher Processor load (5 min average per core) in Zabbix. With Grafana, is it possible? All the servers are in the same group or using the same template (Linux).

Comment: If you search for "grafana top limit" or similar you'll find lots of info in the forums, but the most common answer is that it's not possibile unless you write your own datasource or your own query. As I said, I think that the API are the best way: call a item.get filtering by your group and  item name, then call history.get to get all these items in the last N minutes. Then you have your data and the item IDs, you can plot it with the chart2.php, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972209/display-zabbix-graphs-on-a-custom-web-site